# How can a raspberry pi get time from another pi

Tags: server, ntp

I'm trying to set a slave pi to let get time from master pi using ntp service. The master pi has been set to be a hotspot (which is not connected to the internet) and the slave pi connect to it via wifi. The master pi has its own time and it is an ntp server. Now I can use windows to synchronize the time from the master pi, but when it comes to the slave pi, it doesn't work as I expect, the `ntp.conf` must have something wrong. So how could I configure the `ntp.conf` file to let the slave pi get the time from the master pi?

Updated:
I added a line "server 192.168.42.1 prefer" (which is the master pi's IP address) in the `ntp.conf`, and add # to the line "server 0 debian.pool.ntp.org ibrust" in the slave pi. Then every time slave pi is rebooted, it synchronized, with the master pi's. But if I set another time (like sudo date -s 2016/2/2) in the slave pi after it is rebooted, the time of the slave pi will not synchronize with the master one, and it will keep the time I set. What should I configure to make sure that the slave pi will synchronize with the master pi once in a while, and correct its time? Thanks!

Comment: May be better to ask on ServerFault. As for the question: What's in your ntp.conf and what have you tried?

Comment: The problems have solved, it turns out the ntp does not responsible for synchronize time, and ntpdate responsible for that. So if I use "ntpdate 192.168.42.1" in terminal, the time will be synchronized.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: @kurt wang I wrote that like 3 hours earlier in answer.

Comment: @FlashThunder Yes, I got the problem solved according to your answer, without your answer I would not think of the "ntpdate" issue, thanks!

Comment: @kurt wang ... oh ok, then accept the answer if someone else would look for it, so he wouldn't have to read all those comments, or delete the question if it's not worth to keep, to not to make a mess, please

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get install ntp` <-- server

`apt-get install ntpdate` <-- client